# Order of Reflection Group of Type $A_n, B_n, C_n$

Tags: group-theory, reflection, stabilizer, orbit-stabilizer

The following exercise comes from section 2.11 in Humphreys' book Reflection groups and Coxeter Groups:

> Use the method of this section to derive again the orders of the groups of types $A_n$, $B_n$, and $C_n$.

I have only thought about the type $A_n$ case so far. Depending on how this posts go, I might make a separate one for types $B_n$ and $C_n$.

In section 2.11, Humphreys uses the orbit-stabilizer theorem to deduce the order of the reflection groups of types $F_4$, $E_6$, $E_7$, and $E_8$. In each case, he use the "highest" root $\tilde{\alpha}$ of the root system associated to the group and looks at the stabilizer of it. In each case, he argues that $\tilde{\alpha}$ is orthogonal to all the simple roots except one, and states that the stabilizer/isotropy group must be of a certain type. E.g., in the $F_4$ case, $\tilde{\alpha}$ is orthogonal to every simple root except $\alpha_1$, so its stabilizer group is of type $C_3$ (honestly, I don't see why that's the case but whatever). And then the number of long roots gives the cardinality of the orbit of the highest root, although I don't see why that's the case either. From here, it's easy to work out the order of the group from the orbit-stabilizer theorem, modulo those two steps I don't understand.

So, let $W$ be the reflection the group of type $A_n$. Then $W = S_{n+1}$ which acts naturally acts on $V = \Bbb{R}^{n+1}$ by permuting the standard basis $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^{n+1}$ and then extending this action linearly to all of $V$. The root system is given by

$$\Phi = \{(x_1,...,x_{n+1}) \in V : ||(x_1,...,x_{n+1}||^2 = 2, \sum x_i = 0\} \cap \text{span}_{\Bbb{Z}} \{e_1,....,e_{n+1}\}$$

$$= \{e_i-e_j : 1 \le i \neq j \le n+1\},$$
which consists of $n(n+1)$ vectors, the simple roots are

$$\Delta = \{\alpha_1 = e_1 - e_2,..., \alpha_n = e_n - e_{n+1}\},$$

and $\tilde{\alpha} = e_1 - e_{n+1}$ is the highest root. It's clear that $\tilde{\alpha}$ is orthogonal to every simple root except $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_n$...But what does this tell us about the type of the stabilizer subgroup. In the type $A_n$ case (or any case for that matter), I don't know the number of long roots.

I could use some help working out the all three cases.

Comment: The stabilizer of a point on a face of the fundamental chamber is *generated* by the simple reflections in the stabilizer. In other words, the stabilizer you need is a smaller Coxeter group. For example, the facts you listed show that the stabilizer of the highest root of $A_n$ is a Coxeter group of type $A_{n-2}$ because it is generated by the simple reflections $s_2,s_3,\ldots,s_{n-1}$. From that description you know that $\Phi(A_n)$ has $n(n+1)$ roots. Therefore the orbit-stabilizer theorem tells you that
$$|W(A_n)|=n(n+1) |W(A_{n-2})|.$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen What's the fundamental chamber and how does one prove that the highest root is in it? I think I see why the stabilizer of a point is generated by all the reflections stabilizing it. There is a theorem in the book saying that if $\lambda \in V$, the isotropy group of $\lambda$ is generated by those reflections $s_\alpha$ ($\alpha \in \Phi$) which it contains. However, I searched my book for the term "fundamental chamber" but I couldn't find anything. Also, the simple reflection $s_i$ corresponds to the transposition $(i,i+1)$, right?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  Also, you are saying that the size of the orbit of $\hat{\alpha}$ under $W$ is $n(n+1)$ which is the size of the root system? I'm not sure I see this. Could you elaborate some more?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen And then once we get to $|W(A_n)|=n(n+1) |W(A_{n-2})|$, do we just use induction or something? How do we determine $|W(A_{n-2})|$ without getting circular. Honestly, this problem is annoying because a simple counting argument shows that $|S_n| = n!$...

Comment: Ingredients: 1) the Weyl group acts transitively  on the set of long roots, 2) the highest long root is in the closure of the fundamental chamber, so its stabilizer can be determined, 3) orbit-stabilizer.

Comment: The idea is that ortbi-stabilizer gives a recursive algorithm for finding the order of the Weyl group. There is nothing circular about it because the recurrence refers to a smaller group. $A_n$ was just an example. You need to do $A_1$ and $A_2$ by hand to get started with the recursion. For example with type $E_7$ we can count that there are $126$ roots (all long), and that the stabilizer is a group of type $D_6$, hence of order $2^5\cdot6!$. Therefore the group of type $E_7$ has order $126\cdot2^5\cdot6!$ et cetera.

Comment: But, yeah, I think this way of determining the size of the group is only used with the exceptional types not belonging to an infinite family. That's because we don't have an alternative description of the group readily available. Like in terms of (signed) permutations. I only brought up the connection between $A_n$ and $A_{n-2}$ as an example showing how the recurrence works.

Comment: [Fundamental chamber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_group#Weyl_chambers). May be your book calls it something else.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sorry for the long silence; I got busy with a lot of other things. I have a another question. So, my book defines a group of type $B_n$, and basically it's the group  $S_n \rtimes (\Bbb{Z}/2 \Bbb{Z})^n$. But my book doesn't really define a group of type $C_n$; it just says that you start with $B_n$ and $C_n$ is defined to be its inverse root system, and then they note that $B_2$ and $C_2$ are isomorphic. But what is $C_n$ in general?